# nokogiri xsd validation failed in centos 5.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using nokogiri gem(1.4.1) for xsd validation, it works well in my local machine(ubuntu) and doesn't in my server(centos 5.4), it didn't validate some of the xml tags, below is my code.

```
          inut_xml=request.raw_post
           errors =[]
    xsd = Nokogiri::XML::Schema(File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/user.xsd"))
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(input_xml)
    xsd.validate(doc).each do |error|
        errors << error.message
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have dependency version problem. check installed libxml2 version of cents 5.4 and your installed ubuntu linux and maybe can be nexttime 'yum upgrade'.